# Photoswipe and Ionic Angular only works after second click

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lightbox, photoswipe

I am using Photoswipe 5.4.2 with Lightbox to display full screen a bunch of images when a user clicks on an image. The problem is the first time it fails but works the second time. Here is the code I am using

In my template, I call the `openLightBox()` function when a user clicks on the image or div.

```
<div class="border-light ion-padding" (click)=openLightbox() *ngIf="images.length">
     <div class="ion-padding-vertical">
          <swiper-container autoplay="true" [delay]="4000" [loop]="true"[pagination]="true" [zoom]="true">
              <swiper-slide *ngFor="let image of images;trackBy:trackByFn">
                  <img  class="slide-img" src="{{image._url}}">
                      </swiper-slide>
              </swiper-container>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here the `images` variable is populated once the page is loaded and I can this because the images is displayed in the item view. For each image i get url, width and height which are required for the lightbox

```
prepareImageData() {
    console.log(this.images.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = this.images[i]._url;
      // Use onload event to wait for the image to load
      img.onload = () => {
        var height = img.height;
        var width = img.width;
        if (height && width) {
          let data = {
            src: img.src,
            width: width,
            height: height,
          };
          this.full_screen_images.push(data);
          console.log(data);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

Finally, I configure the lightbox and pass the `full_screen_images`.

```
async openLightbox(index: number = 0) {
    await this.prepareImageData();
    console.log(this.full_screen_images);
    const options = {
      index: index,
      closeSVG:
        '<svg aria-hidden="true" class="pswp__icn" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100" height="125"><path d="M400 145.49L366.51 112 256 222.51 145.49 112 112 145.49 222.51 256 112 366.51 145.49 400 256 289.49 366.51 400 400 366.51 289.49 256 400 145.49z"/></svg>',
      zoom: false,
      arrowPrev: false,
      arrowNext: false,
      bgOpacity: 1,
      dataSource: this.full_screen_images,
    };

    this.lightbox = new PhotoSwipe(options);
    // on() events go here (see below)
    this.lightbox.init();
  }
```